# hover на два блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

здравствуйтe, не подскажите почему при наведение на ссылку не сменяется картинка в arr3 и наоборот при наведении на картинку, менять картинку(#arr3) и цвет текста

```css
.imgBottom{
 width: 141px;
 height: 130px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 22px;
 float: left;
 color:#2987ac;
 font-size: 12.3px;
  background-color:gray;
 
}
.imgBottom a{
 top:10px;
 position: relative;
 color:black;
 font-size: 12.3px;

}

.imgBottom:first-child{
 margin-left: 19px;
}
.imgBottom #arr ,#arr1,#arr2,#arr3,#arr4,#arr5,#arr6{
 position:relative;
 top:12px;
 left:6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 color:#fff;
 
 
}
.imgBottom :hover {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 color:#2987ac;
 
}

.imgBottom #arr3
 background:url(http://iconspot.ru/image.php?width=128&height=128&crop=none&id=13940);
}
.imgBottom:hover a {
 color:#2987ac;
}
.imgBottom:hover #arr3 {
 background:url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0612/GooglePlusInterfaceIcons/w128h1281338911640arrowright2.png);
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgBottom"><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/990114226/e92aea60b7b085c70a9d17ed59b38eea?v=1" >
<a href="#">Строительство и логистика</a>
<img src="" id="arr3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: #arr3у вас img т.е изображение  обычная картинка , в общем фотка и как вы изображению хотите придать background  т.е фон ? `.imgBottom:hover #arr3`  это = `<img src="" id="arr3"/>` вот это

Comment: вы может так хотели ? http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/XKPWjE?editors=110

Answer (score -2):

Сделайте так:

```
    .imgBottom a:hover {
    color:#2987ac;
}
```

Comment: это не работает хотя бы потому, что внутрь `img` нельзя положить `a`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.